# How can I make transform to rotate facing the next waypoint each time reaching a waypoint?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveOnCurvedLines : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public float speed;
    public bool go = false;
    public bool moveToFirstPositionOnStart = false;

    private Vector3[] positions;
    private Vector3[] pos;
    private int index = 0;
    private bool goForward = true;
    private List<GameObject> curvedLinePoints = new List<GameObject>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        curvedLinePoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Curved Line Point").ToList();
        transform.rotation = curvedLinePoints[1].transform.rotation;

        pos = GetLinePointsInWorldSpace();

        if (moveToFirstPositionOnStart == true)
        {
            transform.position = pos[index];
        }
    }

    Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);


        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (go == true)
        {
            Move();
        }
    }

    int counter = 1;
    void Move()
    {
        Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
        float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        bool stillTraveling = true;
        while (stillTraveling)
        {
            Vector3 oldPos = newPos;
            newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[index], distanceToTravel);
            distanceToTravel -= Vector3.Distance(newPos, oldPos);
            if (newPos == pos[index]) // Vector3 comparison is approximate so this is ok
            {
                // when you hit a waypoint:
                if (goForward)
                {
                    bool atLastOne = index >= pos.Length - 1;
                    if (!atLastOne) index++;
                    else { index--; goForward = false; }
                }
                else
                { // going backwards:
                    bool atFirstOne = index <= 0;
                    if (!atFirstOne) index--;
                    else { index++; goForward = true; }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                stillTraveling = false;
            }
        }

        transform.position = newPos;

        counter++;
        transform.rotation = curvedLinePoints[counter].transform.rotation;
    }
}
```

There are 12 waypoints I called the List variable as curvedLinePoints.
The positions array are positions between the curvedLinePoints but I want the transform to rotate facing each next curvedLinePoints point and there are 12 like this.

The way I did it with the counter is wrong and also give exception out of bound index. and I should not doing it in the Update at this place.

In the Start I tried to make the transform to point the next waypoint :

```
transform.rotation = curvedLinePoints[1].transform.rotation;
```

Not sure if it's the right way.

And I also want later to do that it will rotate smooth to the next waypoint and not just rotate at once but first how to make it rotating looking the next waypoint ?

Update, This is what I tried :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveOnCurvedLines : MonoBehaviour
{
    public LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public float speed;
    public bool go = false;
    public bool moveToFirstPositionOnStart = false;
    public float rotSpeed;

    private Vector3[] positions;
    private Vector3[] pos;
    private int index = 0;
    private bool goForward = true;
    private List<GameObject> curvedLinePoints = new List<GameObject>();
    private int numofposbetweenpoints;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        curvedLinePoints = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Curved Line Point").ToList();
        transform.rotation = curvedLinePoints[1].transform.rotation;

        pos = GetLinePointsInWorldSpace();

        numofposbetweenpoints = pos.Length / curvedLinePoints.Count;

        if (moveToFirstPositionOnStart == true)
        {
            transform.position = pos[index];
        }
    }

    Vector3[] GetLinePointsInWorldSpace()
    {
        positions = new Vector3[lineRenderer.positionCount];
        //Get the positions which are shown in the inspector 
        lineRenderer.GetPositions(positions);


        //the points returned are in world space
        return positions;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (go == true)
        {
            Move();
        }
    }

    int counter = 0;
    int c = 1;
    void Move()
    {
        Vector3 newPos = transform.position;
        float distanceToTravel = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        bool stillTraveling = true;
        while (stillTraveling)
        {
            Vector3 oldPos = newPos;
            newPos = Vector3.MoveTowards(oldPos, pos[index], distanceToTravel);
            distanceToTravel -= Vector3.Distance(newPos, oldPos);
            if (newPos == pos[index]) // Vector3 comparison is approximate so this is ok
            {
                // when you hit a waypoint:
                if (goForward)
                {
                    bool atLastOne = index >= pos.Length - 1;
                    if (!atLastOne)
                    {
                        index++;
                        counter++;
                        if (counter == numofposbetweenpoints)
                        {
                            c++;
                            Vector3 targetDirection = (curvedLinePoints[c].transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
                            curvedLinePoints[c].transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection);
                            transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, curvedLinePoints[c].transform.rotation, Time.deltaTime);


                            counter = 0;
                        }
                        if (c == curvedLinePoints.Count - 1)
                        {
                            c = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else { index--; goForward = false; }
                }
                else
                { // going backwards:
                    bool atFirstOne = index <= 0;
                    if (!atFirstOne) index--;
                    else { index++; goForward = true; }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                stillTraveling = false;
            }
        }

        transform.position = newPos;      
    }
}
```

but the rotation part is not working good.

This part not making the transform to rotate smooth facing the next waypoint :

```
Vector3 targetDirection = (curvedLinePoints[c].transform.position - transform.position).normalized;
curvedLinePoints[c].transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDirection);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, curvedLinePoints[c].transform.rotation, Time.deltaTime);
```

If I'm just making LookAt it will face the next waypoint but not smooth with speed factor just will cut rotating facing the next waypoint :

```
transform.LookAt(curvedLinePoints[c].transform, Vector3.up);
```

And I want it to rotate nicer smooth with speed.

Comment: What happens with rotate towards? Is it not rotating at all or is it just very slow? Time.deltaTime is a very small value and may not be a good value to rotate by each frame. You may want something more like "Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed".

Answer (score 1):

To immediately look directly at a target, you want [Transform.LookAt()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html)

```
transform.LookAt(curvedLinePoints[index], Vector3.Up);
```

For smooth rotation, it's a little more complicated:

```
Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(curvedLinePoints[index] - transform.position, Vector3.up);
float rotateSpeed = 90; //degrees per second, adjust as needed
Quaternion newRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
transform.rotation = newRotation;
```

Both of these things should have been easy to find through web searches and by reading the documentation.

Comment: He should probably use something like RotateTowards (https://docs.unity3d.com/ja/current/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html) since the last line says he wants smooth rotations and not to just cut to the correct rotation.

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson You right I updated my question with what I tried using RotateTowards for this but it's still not working. I also tried to use the RotateTowards like in the link you provided but it also didn't work for smooth rotating.

Comment: @DanielJacksonville I've updated my answer with a solution for smooth rotation. In the future, please try a web search and reading the documentation, as these are very basic concepts that it's easy to find solutions for.

Comment: @DanielJacksonville Does this answer your question now?